# Angular Tree Component: get top level parent of current node

Tags: angular, recursion, angular-tree-component

I want to find the top-level parent (on the tree) of the current node.

I have the following code:

```
expandParents(node: any) {
    const parent = node.data.x.parent;

    if (!!parent && this.getLevel(parent) > 0) {
      this.expandParents(parent);
    } else if (!!parent && this.getLevel(parent) === 0) {
      console.log('1. ', parent);
      return parent;
    }
  }

  getTopLevelParent(node: T) {
    const topLevelParent = this.expandParents(node);

    console.log('2. ', topLevelParent);
    return topLevelParent;
  }
```

Below, is what console.log prints:

```
1.  DynamicFlatNode {data: {…}}
2.  undefined
```

Why console.log('2. ', topLevelParent); always returns undefined?

Comment: getTopLevelParent this function called two times that's why 2. is getting undefined

Comment: Replace this **const parent = node.data.x.parent;** code to **const parent = node.data.x.parent ? node.data.x.parent : node;**

Comment: it will resolve your concern

Comment: @AmanGojariya hmm.. still get the same result (undefined) :\

Comment: can you please share code where you have call **getTopLevelParent**  this function?

Comment: @AmanGojariya seems that the last part of code that is executed is the if statement (not the else). I cannot understand how the parent of a node with level 0 corresponds to a node with level > 0 .

Comment: @AmanGojariya onChangeEvent(event, node: any) {
    const topLevelParent = this.treeControl.getTopLevelParent(node);
    console.log('Top-level parent: ', topLevelParent);
}

Comment: I think I understand your problem. I will post answer

Comment: @AmanGojariya still gets undefined. This code seems to be a mystery. : ) Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, somewhere you're getting undefined data so can you please try using below code

```
expandParents(node: any) {
  const parent = node.data && node.data.x && node.data.x.parent ? node.data.x.parent : node;

  if (!!parent && this.getLevel(parent) > 0) {
    this.expandParents(parent);
  } else if (!!parent && this.getLevel(parent) === 0) {
    console.log('1. ', parent);
    return parent;
  }
}

getTopLevelParent(node: T) {
  if (node) {
    const topLevelParent = this.expandParents(node);

    console.log('2. ', topLevelParent);
    return topLevelParent;
  }
}
```